# Springboot reading my yml but is null even if i passing in values

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

This is what my application yml looks like

```
    credit:
     application:
       message: "credit messages"
```

java code

```java
    @Value("${credit.application.message}")
    private String message;

    public void displayConfig() {
        log.info("#####################   \n" + "");

        log.info("#####################   \n" + message);
    }
```

The problem is that my value message is `null` even if i'm setting it in the yml

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Slf4j
public class ConfigServer {

    @Value("${credit.application.message}")
    private String message;

    public void displayConfig() {
        log.info("#####################   \n" + "");

        log.info("#####################   \n" + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the name of your yml file?

Comment: application.yml

Comment: and the location?

Comment: also can you share the full class which hold displayConfig method? also the import of `@Value`

Comment: import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Slf4j
public class ConfigServer {

    @Value("${credit.application.message}")
    private String message;

    public void displayConfig() {
        log.info("#####################   \n" + "");

        log.info("#####################   \n" + message);
    }
}

Comment: where you put the `application.yml` file?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMN7X.png i have this now but still null

Comment: Can't reproduce it, [it is **working**](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/com-example-springconfig/tree/master/demo) for me....Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: i honestly dnt know what i am missing

Comment: annotate `ConfigServer` with `@Configuration` annotation, spring can only inject values into application context beans

Comment: @Deadpool thanks it works. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNQe7.png

Comment: Springboot expects [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) (which is what your example looks like) and that is not the same as [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/), which an XML based format.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `@Configuration` or `@Service` or `@Controller`, .. annotation your class is just a native class not a component class, instead try :

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration // important 
public class ConfigServer {
    @Value("${credit.application.message}")
    private String message;

    public void displayConfig() {
        log.info("##################### \n" + "");
        log.info("##################### \n" + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mrobi you said in your last comment that it works!

Comment: sorry about the confusion. it's working. i made it a Bean then it work